# Python: controlling input to a factorial method

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

I want this python function to handle the user input not to provide a non-integer value (decimals for instance) and through an exception otherwise.

```
    # a function that takes an integer and returns its factorial
def factorial(x):
    try:
        if x == 0:
            return (0)
        else:
            pro = 1
            for i in range(1, x + 1):
                pro *= i
    except(ValueError, TypeError):
        # this part of the code is supposed to handle exception for invalid input5
        print("an error happened")
    return (pro)


# calling the function with validated input
# warning!!! this program my take longer time as your input get larger
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer:"))
if num >= 0:
    print("\n Factorial of " + str(num) + " = " + str(factorial(num)))
else:
    print("Factorial is operated only on positive number");
```

Comment: The factorial of 0 is 1, not 0 as in your code. Otherwise, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `assert` statement here.

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer:"))

assert isinstance(num, int) and num >= 0, 'Factorial is operated only on positive number'
```

If the assertion is false, an `AssertionError` is thrown with the message provided. Furthermore, you can assert this anywhere in your code. Within your function as well, eliminating the need for a try/except block.

---

Here's a solution to your problem with a decorator. The decorator will carry out the assertion before allowing the factorial to be computed.

```
@checknum
def factorial(x):    
    if x == 0:
        return 1 # changing this to 1, not 0
    else:
        pro = 1
        for i in range(1, x + 1):
            pro *= i

    return pro

def checknum(function):
    def wrapper(x):
        assert isinstance(x, int) and x >= 0, 'Factorial is operated only on positive number'
        return function(x)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I copied the entire code to my editor and didn't work.

Comment: @MinilikTesfaye Could you be specific? What error did you get? Is it a syntax error or runtime?

Comment: I should mention that you still call the method with factorial(x). The decorator will work its magic in the background.